# product of two positive operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $A,B\in B(H)$ be positive operators on Hilbert space $H$. Consider operator $C:= AB+BA$. Is operator $C$ positive? While we know $A, B$ is not commute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let
$$
a = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}, \text{ and } b=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Then
$$
c = ab +ba = \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 1 \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix} 
$$
The characteristic polynomial of $c$ is
$$
p(x) = (x-2)(x)-1  = x^2-2x-1
$$
which has a negative root $x = 1- \sqrt{2}$. In particular, $c$ cannot be a positive operator because if $v$ is the corresponding eigen-vector, then
$$
\langle cv,v\rangle = (1-\sqrt{2})\|v\|^2 < 0
$$